# Thread-local storage (TLS) and OpenMP

Tags: c++, thread-safety, openmp

What does OpenMP (e.g. Intel C++ 12 implementation) currently do with the TLS variables declared with __thread in Linux and __declspec(thread) on Windows? Does it make them threadprivate or just ignores TLS?

Found one related paper, but still confused.

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1639501&tag=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980937/openmp-and-thread-local-storage-identifier-with-icc

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, __thread is used to implement OpenMP threadprivate ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z1788dd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) page on MSDN also mentions that) in a number of compilers (VC, gcc, icc).