# OpenMP and Thread Local Storage identifier with icc

Tags: c, openmp, icc, thread-local-storage

This is a simple test code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

__thread int a = 0;

int main() {

    #pragma omp parallel default(none)
    {
        a = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`gcc` compiles this without any problems with `-fopenmp`, but `icc (ICC) 12.0.2 20110112` with `-openmp` complains with

> test.c(7): error: "a" must be specified in a variable list at enclosing OpenMP parallel pragma
>           #pragma omp parallel default(none)

I have no clue which paradigm (i.e. `shared`, `private`, `threadprivate`) applies to this type of variables. Which one is the correct one to use?

I get the expected behaviour when calling a function that accesses that thread local variable, but I have trouble accessing it from within an explicit parallel section.

**Edit:**

My best solution so far is to return a pointer to the variable through a function

```
static inline int * get_a() { return &a; }
```

Comment: Mixing different thread models is probably not such a good idea. Semantically `threadprivate` is probably the closest. Since `__thread` is a compiler extension, you will probably not find much of documentation that links this and OpenMP.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? GCC should not ask you to give `a` an explicit data-sharing class, even when `default(none)` is specified.

Comment: @HristoIliev I am using `icc` 12.0.2. And you are right that this seems to be an issue with `icc`. `gcc` accepts this.

Comment: Try adding `#pragma omp threadprivate(a)` on the next line after the declaration of `a`. It is a bit of tautology since to a great extent both do the same (with some exceptional cases concerning C++ objects).

Comment: @HristoIliev This is the one! Getting rid of the `__thread` specifier and putting `#pragma omp threadprivate` instead even makes my code compatible with Mach-O since `__thread` is unsupported in Mach-O executables. If you post this as an answer then I will happily give you credit.

Comment: By the way, I have never seen the way ICC implements TLS on OS X, but GCC's way is an awful emulation, which is really slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__thread` is roughly analogous to the effect that the `threadprivate` OpenMP directive has. To a great extent (read as when no C++ objects are involved), both are *often* implemented using the same underlying compiler mechanism and therefore are compatible but this is **not guaranteed** to always work. Of course, the real world is far from ideal and we have to sometimes sacrifice portability for just having things working within the given development constraints.

`threadprivate` is a directive and not a clause, therefore you have to do something like:

```
#include "header_providing_a.h"

#pragma omp threadprivate(a)

void parallel_using_a()
{
   #pragma omp parallel default(none) ...
     ... use 'a' here
}
```

GCC (at least version 4.7.1) treats `__thread` as implicit `threadprivate` declaration and you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Funny thing: For gcc on Linux `__thread` and `threadprivate` are synonymous and uses the `FS` segment register on x86. On OS X (Mach-O) `threadprivate` causes gcc to use some emulation called `___emutls_get_address`. For icc the presence of `__thread` (irrelevant of `threadprivate`) on Linux x86 causes the same behaviour as gcc: use of the `FS` segment register. In the absence of `__thread`, but with `threadprivate` icc kicks in with some fairly complicated emulation on both Linux and OS X.

Comment: Passing `-openmp-threadprivate=compat` to icc causes it to treat `threadprivate` in the same way as `__thread` on compatible OSes/architectures.

Comment: @SergeyL.  Has the situation (being slow) of `threadprivate` improved with MacOS? Is it better now with GCC, ICC, or Clang? I have never used OpoenMP with MacOS (and for that matter I have never compiled anything with macOS) but I'm just curious. Is `threadprivate` emulated with ICC on Linux? If so why? On MacOS is there some limitation of Mach-O with TLS?

Comment: @SergeyL. It seems Clang offers options to change the TLS model `-ftls-model`. It also has `-femulated-tls`. That's interesting. I wonder if GCC has something like this. It sounds like `threadprivate` can't be relied on to be implemented well with different OS's and compilers.

Comment: @Zboson, perhaps the different TLS models of Clang correspond to the different TLS implementations in the Intel OpenMP runtime that it uses per default. Intel compilers have the same option.

Comment: @HristoIliev, Clang uses the Intel OpenMP runtime by default? Is this even open source or freely available? I thought Clang used gomp or it's own OpenMP runtime?

Comment: @Zboson, the [Intel OpenMP Runtime](https://www.openmprtl.org/) has been open-sourced quite some time ago and is the basis of the OpenMP support in Clang. It is kind of amazing to see people from IBM working on it too.