# How can we prepare small memory pool where there are certain ranges of location that each thread can independently access?

Tags: c++, openmp, shared-memory

Suppose the function call below:

```
// BigObj is a class instance that consumes memory 
void f(const BigObj& in, BigObj& out) {
      BigObj tmp1, tmp2, tmp3;
      // function calls on in, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3 and output assign out to some value 
}


int main() {
    vector<BigObj> vec_in;
    vector<BigObj> vec_out;
    ...// vec_in here has many elements
    ...// vec_out has the same size of vec_in

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        f(vec_in[i], vec_out[i]);
    }
}
```

The *f* is called by multi-threads.

The problem here is there are temporally huge objects tmp1, tmp2, tmp3.
So, once each thread calls *f*, it allocates and deallocates all the temporal variables, which takes so long time.

In order to avoid this, I want to remove local variabls tmp1, tmp2 and tmp3 , and instead create 3 global arrays (which is first initialized before the for loop) of BigObj as memory pool so that i-th thread only access to the i-th element.

```
BigObj tmp1_pool[num_thread];
BigObj tmp2_pool[num_thread];
BigObj tmp2_pool[num_thread];
```

If I prepare this kind of thing, how can I use it with pragma omp directives?
Is passing an thread id to the function the best option? (if so, I have no idea how to do so anyway...)

Comment: Can't you make the initialization/destruction of `BigObj` cheaper instead? If not, have you considered a pool of `BigObj` objects that worker threads can temporarily claim and return to the pool when they are done with them?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for thread local storage as pertains to OpenMP.  Try reading this post on SO: [OpenMP and Thread Local Storage identifier with icc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19980937/1553090)

Comment: @Botje the number of BigObj in the vector is much latger than the thread size. Thus, pooling is better. Anyway how to do that even with your solution using openmp?

Comment: @paddy not local storage. It should be global. (do i miss something?)

Comment: You could use a [lock-free queue](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue) for example. Just be sure to pre-allocate enough `BigObj` instances, or have your `f` fall back to allocating instances (and then recycling them to the pool).

Comment: @user9414424 you may be missing something, given how you returned the question.  Thread-local storage is basically like having a per-thread global.  It has the same identifier, but each thread that uses it gets its own instance.

Answer (score 0):

For your use-case, you can declare the variable global with `threadprivate`.

```
BigObj tmp1, tmp2, tmp3;
#pragma omp threadprivate(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3)
```

This means, each thread will have it's own default constructed copy of `tmp1` etc, which you can safely use as temporaries within parallel regions.

Arrays or vectors like `BigObj tmp1_pool[num_thread];` can work. But there is the danger of introducing false sharing and destroying performance. It is possible to do this correctly and efficiently, but it is much simpler to just use `threadprivate`.

Another alternative to avoid global variables all-together would be a temporary set for each parallel region, like:

```
struct Tmp { BigObj tmp1; BigObj tmp2; BigObj tmp3; };

void f(const BigObj& in, BigObj& out, Tmp& tmp) {
}


#pragma omp parallel
{
    Tmp tmp;
    #pragma omp for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        f(vec_in[i], vec_out[i], tmp);
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it can be easier to reason about lifetime and dependencies - at the cost of explicit passing of data for performance reasons.
In the end, you have to decide between global variables and tramp data.